# Collecting first item of a list in a list of lists

Tags: python, list, for-loop, iterator

I have a list that looks like the following one:

`my_list = [[[(2,3,4,5)]],[[8,2,4,2]],[[9,0,0,0]]]`

Now, I want to find a way to make a new list `zero_list` whose elements will be the 0th entries of each element in `my_list`. That is

`zero_list = [2, 8, 9]`

How could I make a `for` loop for iterating the 0th element of a list whose elements are lists themselves? Of course in my real example I have a much bigger such list with thousands of entries who are lists themselves.

P.S. I understand this is probably an easy question but I could not figure it out.

Comment: Do sublists have random level of depth?

Comment: All of them are the same. A solution to the example above would help me for a solution to the much larger problem I currently have. There is only 1 level of depth. main list whose entries are lists of real numbers.

Comment: The sample `my_list` has three lists which have 3, 2, 2 depths respectively. Can you change your sample to reflect your situation?

Comment: is tuple also part of your code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any depth list you can use this recursive function

```
def get_first(seq):
    if isinstance(seq, (tuple, list)):
        return get_first(seq[0])
    return seq

def get_zero_list(seq):
    return [get_first(i) for i in seq]



my_list = [[[[[[[[(2,3,4,5)]]]]]]],[[8,2,4,2]],[[9,0,0,0]]]

print(get_zero_list(my_list)) # [2, 8, 9]

my_list = [[[[[[[[(2,3,4,5)]]]]]]],[[[[[[[('first', 3)]]]], 2, 3],2,4,2]],[[([['a', 2]]),0,0,0]]]

print(get_zero_list(my_list)) # [2, 'first', 'a']
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I need. I need a list whose output is the first element of each sublist.

Comment: That is a very good answer. I am wondering though if there is a standard method to do this instead of defining these two functions.

Comment: thanks, it was an interesting question as well, afaik none exists, but if I do find one, I will edit it in

Comment: Why I struggle to generalize to the second index? 

`def get_second(seq):
    if isinstance(seq, (tuple, list)):
        return get_second(seq[1])
    return seq

def get_first_list(seq):
    return [get_second(i) for i in seq]`

Comment: what should you do if there is no element in second or the `nth` index? what is the behavior you expect? the new list should only include the `nth` element only if it exists in a nested list?

Comment: where you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

```
Zero_list = [ items[0] for sublist in my_list for items in sublist]
```